# Why entrap B'rurya?

Tags: rashi, sin, arayot, tannaim, masecheth-avodah-zarah

*Rashi*, *Avoda Zara* 18 *amud* 2, in my own translation:

> One time, [*B'rurya*] belittled the sages' having said that women's knowledge is light on them. [Her husband, *Rabi Meir*,] told her, "By your life, your end will be to admit to their words." He commanded one of his students to test her into sin. [The student] begged her many days until she agreed. When she was informed, she strangled herself; *Rabi Meir* fled to *Bavel* from shame.

Why did *Rabi Meir* choose such an extreme way ([entrapment](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrapment) for a sin — and for such a terrible sin!) to prove his point?